# How to store multiple output columns returned by stored proc in shell using sqlplus

Tags: bash, oracle, unix, plsql, sqlplus

I have o read values returned by sql stored proc to variables in shell script. I was able to achieve this with single variable but not for two variables.

Oracle stored proc

```
PROCEDURE get_values (ip_var   IN  NUMBER,
op_var1  OUT VARCHAR2,
op_var2  OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
    SELECT col1, col2
    INTO   op_var1, op_var2
    FROM   emp
    WHERE  emp_id = ip_var;
END;
```

Calling this proc in unix bash as

```
sql_status=`sqlplus -silent /nolog << END
whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode
whenever oserror exit -2
set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off scan off serveroutput on
connect $DATABASE 
declare
var1   VARCHAR2(20);
var2   VARCHAR2(20);
begin
get_values($input_val, var1, var2);
end;
/
exit;
END`
```

I need to assign var1 and var2 further in my program. So how can I achieve this?

Comment: You can simply assign the values to 2 variables declared in your bash script like `v1=$var1;` & `v2=$v2;` and use `v1 and v2` in rest of your program.

Answer (score 0):

I know not how to do this interface between PL/SQL (Oracle Server side language) and Unix. You may want to have a jdbc connector for more advanced use.

A solution for your problem is **to build an output string** directly from the query (or you could use a procedure, and output the result with `dbms_output`), and process the string in your shell.

Here is how (without procedure):

```
COL_SEP="%"
RETURN_STRING=`sqlplus -silent /nolog << END
whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode
whenever oserror exit -2
set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off scan off serveroutput on
connect $DATABASE 
  SELECT col1 ||'${COL_SEP}'|| col2
  FROM   emp
  WHERE  emp_id = ip_var;
exit;
END`

echo "RETURN CODE IS: $? "
echo "RETURN STRING : ${RETURN_STRING} "
v1=`echo ${RETURN_STRING} | cut -d${COL_SEP} -f1 `
v2=`echo ${RETURN_STRING} | cut -d${COL_SEP} -f2 `

echo "Variables set: V2:${v2} and V1:${v1}"
```

And you can do it with `dbms_output.put_line` in a pl/sql block:

```
declare
  v varchar2(100) := '00';
begin
  select 'a'||'${COL_SEP}'||'b' into v from dual;
  dbms_output.put_line(v);
end;
/
```

Hope it helps